# Backtrack R3 can't find wlan

Tags: networking, backtrack, networkcard, wlan

I have installed Backtrack R3 in virtualbox, but i cant find any wireless connections.
Cant find anything in wicd either.
What i want to do is to run `airmon-ng start wlan0` in terminal, and after that `wash -i mon0`
But i find nothing then i run `airmon-ng start wlan0` and the command `wash -i mon0` doesn't work at all.

`airmon-ng start wlan0` giving this output:
[airmon-ng start wlan0 http://billedeupload.dk/images/axVXC.png](http://billedeupload.dk/images/axVXC.png)!

`wash -i mon0` giving this output:
[wash -i mon0 http://billedeupload.dk/images/3XGZB.png](http://billedeupload.dk/images/3XGZB.png)!

Have no idead about what i need to do

Comment: Have you configured your VM to have access to the wifi card?

Comment: Im not sure how i do that, but i can connect the internet through the browser in backtrack, but i cant view the wireless connections.

Comment: OK, please post the output of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`. You should also check the setting in virtualbox and make sure you have set up the wireless card.

Comment: I dont know hot to check the settings in virtualbox, but here are the configs.

`ifconfig`
![ifconfig](http://billedeupload.dk/images/6mkh.png)!

`iwconfig`
![iwconfig](http://billedeupload.dk/images/yz00R.png)!